# Intersection of dates with Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is the query I'm riding on the repository of my Ad:

```
    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->lte(':date', 'ad.date'));
    if (array_key_exists('date', $paramFetcher)) {
        $query->setParameter('date', new \DateTime($paramFetcher['date']));
    } else {
       $query->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));
    }

    if (array_key_exists('dateFinal', $paramFetcher)) {
       $query
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->lte('ad.dateFinal', ':dateFinal'))
            ->setParameter('dateFinal', new \DateTime($paramFetcher['dateFinal']));
    } else {// Ad of treatment that has expired
       $query
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->gte('ad.dateFinal', ':dateFinal'))
            ->setParameter('dateFinal', new \DateTime('now'));
    }
```

My intention is to make the intersection between the date passed by parameter (which is the start date and end) and the period of my Ad (which is the date and dateFinal).

what better way to do?

Because I was thinking of apena use to_date to make the last date for paremetro is understood to date. Of course as he has no to_date in Doctrine2 I would have to make a custom DQL.

But I would like you to help me find a better solution to cleaner.

Comment: try use this statement  `lte('ad.dateFinal', 'to_date(:date)')`  instead of this: `lte('to_date(:date)', 'ad.dateFinal')`

Comment: So it does not make much sense to the logical because FinalDate Ad must be greater than start date of the search.

And currently testing to the end date of the search with the start date of the ad. And when I reverse this in the question he simplemesmente returns all ads ever. I tried the same query postgres and the same thing happened. So I think the error is in the logic, but I can not find him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my logic:

```
//the start date of the search must be less than the end date of Ad
if (array_key_exists('date', $paramFetcher)) {
    $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $paramFetcher['date'])));
        $query
        ->andWhere($query->expr()->gte('ad.dateFinal', 'to_date(:date)'))
        ->setParameter('date', new \DateTime($date));
}

//the search deadline must always be greater than the date of the Ad
if (array_key_exists('dateFinal', $paramFetcher)) {
    $dateFinal = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $paramFetcher['dateFinal'])));
        $query
        ->andWhere($query->expr()->lte('ad.date', 'to_date(:dateFinal)'))
        ->setParameter('dateFinal', new \DateTime($dateFinal));
}
```

to the treatment of ad has expired, the search is always done, where the final date of the announcement must be greater than today's date

```
->andWhere($query->expr()->gte('ad.dateFinal', 'to_date(:today)'))
->setParameter('today', new \DateTime('now'))
```

config.yml

```
orm:
    ...
    dql:
        ...
        datetime_functions:
            to_date: Delivve\WebBundle\DQL\ToDate
```

ToDate.php

```
class ToDate extends FunctionNode
{
    public $date;

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return "to_date(" . $this->date->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ", 'YYYY-MM-DD')";
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->date = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

The date was going through the parameter is coming in the format 'dd / mm / yyyy' put the Datetime function has a problem with a / so there is that part of the code:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $paramFetcher['date'])));
```

This is often very confusing because several countries use padões different dates.